# Bug: Retag button exits First Posts review mode

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, google-chrome

When I click on the <kbd>Retag</kbd> button the page switches from `https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/...` to the https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12488299/edit?tagsonly=true URL and never comes back.

However I can return to the review mode by clicking several times on the browser's Back button, and then I am allowed to click on <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button.

In contrast, the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button keeps the same URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clicking "retag" from review now allows you to edit the tags inline and then click <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>.